# What is a good way to solve the following linear system? (repeatedly)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-solver, helmholtz-equation

Let $n,m\in \mathbb{N}$ be such that $m\ge n$.

Let $M_1\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $\{M_{2},M_{3} \} \subset \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ be symmetric positive definite and computationally cheap to invert.  You can think of them as a diagonal matrix.  Let $S\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ be full rank.  Let $B\in \mathbb{R}^m$.  I am interested in solving the following linear system over a range of $\omega \in \mathbb{R}$.
$$
\begin{align*}
 \left\lbrack 
   \begin{array}{cc}
   -i \omega  M_1& S\\
   -S^\mathrm{T} &  -i\omega M_2+ M_3
   \end{array}
 \right\rbrack
\left\lbrack
  \begin{array}{c}
U\\Q
\end{array}
\right\rbrack = \left\lbrack \begin{array}{c} 0\\B \end{array} \right\rbrack.
\end{align*}
$$

If $M_1$ and $M_2$ were both $0$ this would be a saddle point problem and if $M_3$ was zero this would be a Helmholtz problem.  I am interested in solving this equation over a range of values of $\omega$, so reusing decompositions might be useful. This system comes from a Telegrapher's equation.

I am writing to inquire if there is a body of research on these types of problem.  I know the research for the saddle point problems and Helmholtz problem is pretty extensive.  Any ideas or suggestions are appreciated.

Edit.

This is what I am planning on doing, without getting a better idea from here.

Writing $U= U_R + i U_I$ and $Q= Q_R + i Q_I$ and rewriting the system by equating real and imaginary parts we get

$$
\left\lbrack
\begin{array}{cccc}
  -\omega M_1 & 0 & 0 & S\\
  0 & \omega M_1& S&0\\
 0& -S^\mathrm{T}& -\omega M_2 & M_3\\
  -S^{\mathrm{T}}&0&M_3& \omega M_2
\end{array}
\right\rbrack
\left\lbrack
\begin{array}{c}
  U_R\\
  U_I\\
  Q_R\\
  Q_I
\end{array}
\right\rbrack
= 
\left\lbrack 
\begin{array}{c}
 0\\
 0\\
 0\\
 B
\end{array}
\right\rbrack.
$$

Eliminating $U_I$ and $U_R$ from these we get

$$
  \left\lbrack
    \begin{array}{cc}
    \omega M_3 &
       S^\mathrm{T} M_1^{-1} S - \omega^2 M_2\\
       S^\mathrm{T} M_1^{-1} S - \omega^2 M_2& \omega M_3
    \end{array}
  \right\rbrack
  \left\lbrack
    \begin{array}{c}
      Q_R\\
      Q_I
    \end{array}
  \right\rbrack
  = 
  \left\lbrack
  \begin{array}{c}
    \omega B\\0
  \end{array}
  \right\rbrack.
$$

Now we have a standard saddle point problem.  I plan on solving it using a Schur complement (inner/outer CG solves) method.  Note that I will use the $\omega M_3$ matrices as "pivots" because there exists $\omega$ for which 
$S^\mathrm{T} M_1^{-1} S - \omega^2 M_2$  is singular.  Having obtained $Q_I$ and $Q_R$ we can use the eliminated equations to recover $U_I$ and $U_R$.

What I don't like about this approach is that there is no reuse.  I mean the method doesn't achieve any economies of scale even though it will solve many closely related problems.

Comment: How big are $n$ and $m$ likely to be? Have you tried a block factorization? That should let you reuse factorizations of all of the submatrices, though you will have to refactor $i\omega M_2+M_3$ each time you change $\omega$ unless there's some very special structure in $M_2$ and $M_3$.

Comment: The matrices will be as can big as can fit on the computer's RAM. (normal workstation not a super computer). The $M$ matrices are actually very sparse and almost diagonal so inverting them for a given RHS is a trivial operation.  $m$  will be $3$ times $n$ for $3$- dimensional problems and and $2$ times $n$ for $2$ dimensional problems.  As for as factorizations, I really only think it would be worthwhile to to factor $S$, maybe into some sort of sparse SVD.

Comment: @BillBarth I can show you what I plan on doing if I don't get a better idea here.  I will add that as an edit to the question.  What do you mean be a block factorization?  Something like how one can solve a saddle point problem using inner and outer CG solvers?

Comment: [Do block-wise Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement).

Comment: "Do block-wise Gaussian elimination" -- which is also known as forming the "Schur complement" in this context.

Comment: @BillBarth I added my proposed solution.  Any thoughts?  I appreciate it.

Comment: Looks like $M_1$ and $M_3$ factorizations could be saved. I know you said they were cheap to invert, but it might be a place to start. If $\omega$ changes slowly, you may find that prior solutions are good starting guesses that help accelerate your inner solves anyway.

Comment: @BillBarth So nothing glaringly obviously wrong or inappropriate as far as you see it?  Thanks.

Comment: @fred, seems fine, but I haven't checked your arithmetic. Ought to be easy enough to implement and see how it goes.

Comment: Actually I think there is a mistake in the arithmetic.  I spent probably 20 minutes making sure there wasn't one before I posted the edit :).  I think one still got through.  Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this is late, but I've been thinking about an iterative solution of this which might be an alternative. So you're solving $(\omega A+B)x = b$ for $x$ with $A$ easily invertible. 
Can you make an iterative version as 
$$\omega A x^{(i+1)} + Bx^{(i)} = b,$$ or equivalently 
$$x^{(i+1)} = \omega^{-1}A^{-1}b - \omega^{-1}A^{-1}Bx^{(i)}.$$ You can precalculate $A^{-1}b$ and $A^{-1}B$, and as @BillBarth said, you could try the $x$ for the previous $\omega$ as your starting guess. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Was going to comment this but not enough rep. Can delete if it's useless.

Comment: Hi, I think this is valid.  I will check and try to get an idea of the spectrum of the $A^{-1}B$ operator to see how fast this will converge.  It looks like for large $\omega$ it will converge fast.

Comment: Also, since you're only doing the inversion once, could check out $$x^{(i+1)} = B^{-1}b - \omega B^{-1}Ax^{(i)}$$

Comment: This will only work for $\omega$ large enough.  For your first example, we need that $\left\|\omega^{-1} A^{-1}B \right\| <1$.  This is a pretty drastic restriction on $\omega$ in my application since $ \left\| A^{-1}B \right\| \to \infty$ as the mesh gets smaller.  There might be a way to fix this though.  Thanks for the idea.